# Authenticate users through Google using only an OAuth2 access token

Tags: authentication, google, oauth

I have a question about having users logon to my service using their Google Credentials. I've gone through the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) documentation provided by Google.

The documentation mentions an `id_token` (JWT token) as the primary authentication token that can be passed around and verified by the application.

On the other hand, together with the id_token, the Google Oauth 2.0 API also returns an access token (that can be long-lived depending on the `access_type`)

Now, Facebook and Twitter also use OAuth to allow third party webapps with a "login using twitter" or "login using facebook" button. They assume that when an access token is retrieved through their APIs it considers the user `authenticated`.

Wouldn't the same be possible with Google? If I just use their OAuth 2.0 API to retrieve an access token and verify the access token by retrieving some user info like email, would that be considered a valid authentication flow ? Or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/49110/37657) may answer your question. The best solution is to use OpenID Connect (id_token) since this will be the standard way to do it (still a draft).